# Pykwalify: YAML Schema validation error

Tags: python, yaml

I am writing a config file in `YAML` and its corresponding schema in `PyKwalify`.

when I compile with `pykwalify`, I get this error

```
NotMappingError: error code 6: Value: None is not of a mapping type: Path: '/'
```

what does this error imply?

Comment: Erro r is missing in the question:      NotMappingError: error code 6: Value: None is not of a mapping type: Path: '/'

Answer (score 1):

It implies that instead of providing a mapping, which could have the form of a block style:

```
a: 1
b: 2
```

of a flow style:

```
{a: 1, b: 2}
```

you provided the null scalar (`null`, `~`) or no scalar:

```
x:
```

or

```
x: null
```

would load `None` in Python as value for the key `x`, whereas

```
x:
  a: 1
  b: 1
```

would load a dictionary/mapping as the value for key `x`. Please note that is you make mistakes with indentation or mix in TAB characters you can get something that looks OK in your editor but doesn't parse as expected.